# Outlook - Share Mail Folders without Exchange

Tags: windows-8.1, microsoft-outlook-2013, shared-folders

I have the following Setup:

- 2 Client-PCs in a local Network, both Windows 8.1)
- 1 Server with Microsoft Server 2012

Both client PCs use Outlook 2013 and receive(POP) and send(SMTP) mail through an external provider.

What I want to achieve :

Have a shared email-folder, to which both PCs can save mails to and read mails from.

Is it possible to achieve this without Microsoft Exchange? I don't want to buy it or go through the setup process...

Comment: `1.` There's no such thing as "Microsoft Server 2013". `2.` There are a number of email server programs available that you can use. hMailServer is but one of those.

Comment: Removed that typo

Comment: Do you mean Windows Server 2012?

If you ISP supports IMAP, then use IMAP. This way both PCs can access the same email box via IMAP. When things change in one Outlook, the other Outlook will show the changes too.